# A função padrão de saída do Java já aceitou diversos parâmetros?

Tags: java

Minha professora ensinou para a classe a usar o `System.out.println("Mensagem")` dessa forma para a turma (o tipo de `total_alunos` não importa):

```
System.out.println("Existem ", total_alunos, " alunos na classe.");
```

Depois de pipocar uns erros nos computadores eu disse que era necessário realizar a concatenação da string através do `+`, o que funcionou, porém ela disse que com a vírgula também deveria funcionar. Em algum momento, foi possível executar essa função da maneira apresentada acima? Se sim, em qual versão do Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Talvez sua professora esteja confundindo o `println()` com o `printf()`, pois coisa similar ao que você deseja pode ser feita assim:

```
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int totalAlunos = 10;
        System.out.printf("Existem %d %s", totalAlunos, " alunos na classe.");
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> Existem 10  alunos na classe.

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) o `printf()` aceita uma quantidade variável de parâmetros e sua assinatura é a seguinte:

```
public PrintStream printf(String format, Object... args)
```

PS: Preste atenção no `%d` e `%s` dentro do primeiro par de aspas duplas que são os especificadores de formato dos demais argumentos, diferente de como está no código da sua pergunta que não os possui.

Já o `println()` não aceita vários parâmetros e não há como passar vários argumentos para ele a não ser concatenando-os e transformando em apenas um, entretanto, não há como concatenar com vírgula nem nunca houve.

Comment: Foi exatamente o que aconteceu @Math, obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Se você observar o Método `println(String)` do tipo `PrintStream`, não aceita como argumentos `String` , `Qualquertipo` ,`String`, com isso a necessidade de se concatenar utilizando `+`.

Isso também é valido caso você tente passar um `Object`.

**Exemplo Abaixo :**

```
 System.out.println("Linked account: "+  client.getAccountInfo().displayName + " account: ");
```

[Link para referência no Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out)

Comment: Caso queira adicionar o link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta @Math

Answer (score 0):

Tente subistituir o codigo:

```
System.out.println("Existem ", total_alunos, " alunos na classe.");
```

por

```
System.out.println("Existem "+ total_alunos + " alunos na classe.");
```

a saída sera:

> Existem 5 alunos na classe.

Comment: Você leu a pergunta dele?